# Insert values into timestamp field mysql using rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, timestamp

I migrated the table to have 2 extra columns with :timestamp field as below

```
class AddingStartAndEndTimeForQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :questions, :eventMode, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :questions, :eventModeStartTime, :timestamp
    add_column :questions, :eventModeEndTime, :timestamp
  end
end
```

I'm unable to insert timestamp in this field manually from rails console.

I tried

```
q.eventModeStartTime = Time.now
q.eventModeStartTime = Time.zone.now
q.eventModeStartTime = DateTime.now
q.eventModeStartTime = Time.now.to_s(:db)
```

Mysql error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2015-09-23 22:46:28.109.109000' for column 'eventModeStartTime'
```

How to insert manually? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: [Here](http://www.question-defense.com/2008/08/13/timestamp-support-rails-and-mysqlpostgresqloracle) written that MySQL doesn't support milliseconds in timestamp columns

Comment: any suggestions? what should I do? @GeneralFailure

Comment: Drop milliseconds (with data type changing of course) or change dbms
Or ask MySQL support

Answer (score 0):

Rails timestamps is a method used in migrations only, part of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters, otherwise it would be date, datetime or json(mysql)(array of datetimes):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb, line 576
def timestamps(options = {})
  @base.add_timestamps(name, options)
end
```

Usage example purpose

```
class CreateSessions < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**In ur example, at below:**

```
add_column :questions, :eventModeStartTime, :timestamp
add_column :questions, :eventModeEndTime, :timestamp
```

**change it to:**

```
add_column :questions, :eventModeStartTime, :datetime, null: false
add_column :questions, :eventModeEndTime, :datetime, null: true
```

**U will be able to set the attr like this:**

```
question.eventModeEndTime = DateTime.now
```